# Pyftdi - ValueError: No Backend Available. Is there any troubleshooting for fixed this error abour windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spi, libusb

I'm creating .exe file with pyinstaller, when I run the created .exe file ,  the error is shown in the console:

> ValueError: No backend available.

In develop I don't have this problem.

I found that copying the libusb-1.0.dll file to C:\Windows\System32 or C:\Windows\SysWOW64 should work, but this does not work for me.

another solution is download and install libusb-win32-devel-filter-1.2.6.0.exe. It does not work for me either.

I'm using *Python 3.7* and import library *pyftdi*

> from pyftdi.spi import SpiController, SpiIOError

Any idea what else can I do?

Actual results in my console is:

```
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\spi.py", line 319, in configure 
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 471, in open_mpsse_from_url 
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 309, in get_identifiers
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\usbtools.py", line 342, in parse_url 
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\ftdi.py", line 390, in find_all 
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\usbtools.py", line 58, in find_all 
 File "site-packages\pyftdi\usbtools.py", line 231, in _find_devices 
 ValueError: No backend available 
 Failed to execute script view
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem had also baffled me for quite a while until I found by searching the talks happened there. It might help you.
Essentially, a walkaround is to use --add-binary command option to add libusb0.dll from system32 directory to dist directory of the pyinstaller output.

Comment: Sorry for the amateur answer, I try to correct it with my own words and submit again.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--add-binary` command to make `libusb0.dll` in the `.exe` file. My cmd is like this:

```
pyinstaller -F -w main.py --add-data "libusb0.dll;."
```